# Need Ctrl+shift+N keydown event in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to bind Ctrl+shift+N keydown event form Chrome browser, but it is not working. Following is the snippet of code:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
    console.log(e.which);
    console.log(e.ctrlKey);
    console.log(e.shiftKey);
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.which === 78) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Ctrl+Shift+N');
        return false;
    }
});
```

On the other browsers its working fine, since Chrome browser has already assigned this shortcut for **"New incognito window"**. So is there any way to prevent this default behavior or catch this event ?

Comment: Are you trying to stop people opening an incognito window?

Comment: Don't override custom key-bindings, *regardless of your intentions*; it does nothing but annoy users that're used to, and wish to use, those key-bindings.

Comment: @DavidThomas: Oh, I don't know. I'm pretty happy that Google Docs overrides Ctrl+U to mean underline rather than view source.

Comment: No, :) im not trying to stop incognito browsing. As there is requirement of that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: true, but that's done sensibly to reflect the key-bindings used in word processors, though I accept that it's something of a special case. If someone overrode the Ctrl+1, Ctrl+2 key bindings for tab-switching I would, personally, be annoyed.

Comment: @DavidThomas: The point is it depends on the key binding ("view source" just isn't as useful/important as tab switching) and the use case of the web page/app. Perhaps if Ctrl+1 were sufficiently important in the web app, you'd accept it. (Or perhaps not.) (Bad news, btw: Chrome lets the page intercept it, unlike Ctrl+N or Ctrl+Shift+N. :-) )

Comment: @DavidThomas: Thank you for the Ctrl+1 and such reminder, btw!